# execute two sql queries in single api call in nodejs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, connection

this is my first table of shop

```
CREATE TABLE `shop` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `shopId` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shopPassword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `shopStatus` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
 `phone` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `shopId` (`shopId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and this is the second table shopaddress

```
CREATE TABLE `shopaddress` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `shopNo` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `complex` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `landmark` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `street` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `area` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `shop_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `shop_id` (`shop_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `shopaddress_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`shop_id`) REFERENCES `shop` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to add rows in both the table in a single API call using nodejs.
also, I want to add that foreign key reference in the second table that this address belongs to this shop.

This my current code which is throwing errors
can I get a correct way to go about such scenarios

```
module.exports = {
    add: (data, callBack) => {
        // Begin Transaction  
        pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            connection.beginTransaction(err => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err
                }
                var shop_query = 'INSERT INTO shop (name, shopId, shopPassword, shopStatus, phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';


                connection.query(shop_query, [data.name, shortid.generate(), shortid.generate(), data.shopStatus, data.phone], (err, results) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return connection.rollback(_ => {
                            throw err
                        })
                    }
                    console.log(results.insertId)
                    let lastId = results.insertId

                    var shopaddress_query = 'INSERT INTO shopaddress (shopNo, complex, landmark, street, area, city, shop_id) VALUES ((?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';


                    connection.query(shopaddress_query, [data.shopNo, data.complex, data.landmark, data.street, data.area, data.city, lastId], (err, results) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return connection.rollback(_ => {
                                throw err
                            })
                        }
                        connection.commit(err => {
                            if (err) {
                                connection.rollback(_ => {
                                    throw err
                                })
                            }
                            connection.end()
                            callBack(null, results)
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    },
```

Comment: What error you receive?

Comment: at Parser._parsePacket (D:\Users\sagar\Desktop\projects\StartUp\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10) {
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO shopaddress (shopNo, complex, landmark, street, area, city, shop_id) VALUES ((6,'poonam','near fun fiesta','0 road','shreeprastha','nalllasopara',20)" @SlavaRozhnev

Comment: You have extra bracket here `VALUES ((?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

Comment: ohhh my goshh, u saved my life @SlavaRozhnev

Comment: Is your tables correlation one to many? (One shot can have more then one address?). If no you can simplify your tables by remove autoincreament from addresses table and use shop_id as primary key

Comment: oh, thanks for the knowledge, in my case I guess I'll probably need one to many relationship in the future.@SlavaRozhnev